# Failed to probe capabilities for /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64: internal error: Failed to start QEMU binary

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, libvirt, virt-manager

I've just launched "virt-manager" on my Ubuntu 21.04 and with my big surprise I've seen the error "**kvm is not available. It could means that the kvm package is not installed and so on**" ; this is not true. I've installed kvm and it is working great,as u can see the image below :

[image]

give a look at what the terminal is telling : "**/dev/kvm exists ; kvm acceleration can be used**". What Am I supposed to believe ? What's missing ?

```
# apt install qemu-kvm libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-x86' instead of 'qemu-kvm'
qemu-system-x86 is already the newest version (1:5.2+dfsg-9ubuntu3.1).

libvirt-clients is already the newest version (7.0.0-2ubuntu2).
libvirt-daemon-system is already the newest version (7.0.0-2ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.

# virt-host-validate

  QEMU: Checking for hardware virtualization                                 : PASS
  QEMU: Checking if device /dev/kvm exists                                   : PASS
  QEMU: Checking if device /dev/kvm is accessible                            : PASS
  QEMU: Checking if device /dev/vhost-net exists                             : PASS
  QEMU: Checking if device /dev/net/tun exists                               : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpu' controller support                         : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpuacct' controller support                     : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpuset' controller support                      : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'memory' controller support                      : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'devices' controller support                     : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'blkio' controller support                       : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for device assignment IOMMU support                         : PASS
  QEMU: Checking if IOMMU is enabled by kernel                               : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for secure guest support                                    : WARN (Unknown if this platform has Secure Guest support)
   LXC: Checking for Linux >= 2.6.26                                         : PASS
   LXC: Checking for namespace ipc                                           : PASS
   LXC: Checking for namespace mnt                                           : PASS
   LXC: Checking for namespace pid                                           : PASS
   LXC: Checking for namespace uts                                           : PASS
   LXC: Checking for namespace net                                           : PASS
   LXC: Checking for namespace user                                          : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'cpu' controller support                         : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'cpuacct' controller support                     : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'cpuset' controller support                      : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'memory' controller support                      : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'devices' controller support                     : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'freezer' controller support                     : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'blkio' controller support                       : PASS
   LXC: Checking if device /sys/fs/fuse/connections exists                   : PASS
```

Again :

```
● libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-07-28 13:18:31 CEST; 41min ago
TriggeredBy: ● libvirtd-admin.socket
             ● libvirtd-ro.socket
             ● libvirtd.socket
       Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
             https://libvirt.org
   Main PID: 2091 (libvirtd)
      Tasks: 21 (limit: 32768)
     Memory: 49.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/libvirtd.service
             ├─2091 /usr/sbin/libvirtd
             ├─2405 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper
             └─2406 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper

Jul 28 12:45:30 Z390-AORUS-PRO libvirtd[2091]: internal error: Failed to start QEMU binary /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 for probing: libvirt:  error : cannot execute binary /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64: Permission denied
Jul 28 12:45:30 Z390-AORUS-PRO libvirtd[2091]: Failed to probe capabilities for /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64: internal error: Failed to start QEMU binary /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 for probing: libvirt:  error : cannot execute binary /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64: Permission denied
Jul 28 13:58:54 Z390-AORUS-PRO libvirtd[2091]: internal error: libxenlight state driver is not active
Jul 28 13:58:54 Z390-AORUS-PRO libvirtd[2091]: End of file while reading data: Input/output error
Jul 28 13:58:54 Z390-AORUS-PRO libvirtd[2091]: invalid argument: could not find capabilities for arch=x86_64 domaintype=qemu 
Jul 28 13:58:54 Z390-AORUS-PRO libvirtd[2091]: internal error: Cannot find suitable emulator for x86_64
Jul 28 13:58:54 Z390-AORUS-PRO libvirtd[2091]: internal error: Failed to start QEMU binary /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 for probing: libvirt:  error : cannot execute binary /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64: Permission denied
Jul 28 13:58:54 Z390-AORUS-PRO libvirtd[2091]: Failed to probe capabilities for /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64: internal error: Failed to start QEMU binary /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 for probing: libvirt:  error : cannot execute binary /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64: Permission denied
Jul 28 13:59:06 Z390-AORUS-PRO libvirtd[2091]: internal error: Failed to start QEMU binary /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 for probing: libvirt:  error : cannot execute binary /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64: Permission denied
Jul 28 13:59:06 Z390-AORUS-PRO libvirtd[2091]: Failed to probe capabilities for /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64: internal error: Failed to start QEMU binary /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 for probing: libvirt:  error : cannot execute binary /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64: Permission denied
```

Comment: Are SELinux or AppArmor running/enforcing policies that are preventing `/usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64` from executing?

Comment: Hint: https://github.com/kubevirt/kubevirt/issues/4303

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the obvious.

```
cannot execute binary /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64: Permission denied
```

Try stopping AppArmor and then restart `libvirtd` and relaunch `virt-manager`

```
sudo systemctl stop apparmor
```